# Enum.GetName() for bit fields?

Tags: c#, parsing, enums, bit-fields

It looks like `Enum.GetName()` doesn't work if the enum has been decorated with a `[Flags]`attribute.

The **[documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname.aspx)** doesn't specify anything related to this limitation.

I've noticed the debugger is able to display something like **Tree |  Fruit**. Is there a way to retrieve the text string describing the combined flags?

---

Following code display `Red`.

```
public enum FavoriteColor
{
    Red,
    Blue,
    WeirdBrownish,
    YouDoNotEvenWantToKnow,
}

var color = FavoriteColor.Red;
Console.WriteLine(Enum.GetName(typeof(FavoriteColor), color));   // => "Red"
```

Whereas this one doesn't output anything....

```
[Flags]
public enum ACherryIsA
{
    Tree = 1,
    Fruit = 2,
    SorryWhatWasTheQuestionAgain = 4,
}

var twoOfThree = ACherryIsA.Fruit | ACherryIsA.Tree;
Console.WriteLine(Enum.GetName(typeof(ACherryIsA), twoOfThree));   // => ""
```

Comment: `Enum.GetName(typeof(ACherryIsA), twoOfThree));` would work if your twoOfThree value actually matched one of the flags. It doesn't work because it's value is a composition of multiple flag values: `(1|2) = 3` which doesn't match any single flag value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
string s = twoOfThree.ToString();
```

or:

```
Console.WriteLine(twoOfThree);
```

If you want to do it manually, split the value into bits, and test what flags you need to add to make that flag. A bit of coding, but not much.

Comment: ZOMG! I didn't even think about trying ToString(). Thanks for the answer and sorry for the dumb question...

Comment: What if you do not know the type of enum at compile time? E.g if you want to do something like `void PrintFlags(Type enumType, int enumValue)`

Comment: @zespri `Enum.ToObject(enumType, enumValue)` gives you the value *typed as the enum*, for the purposes of `ToString()` etc

Comment: Thank you that works. I also came across this: `Enum.Format(enumType, enumVal, "g")`, which also works.

Comment: @zespri fair enough - nice find

Answer (score 4):

Why not `twoOfThree.ToString()`?

twoOfThree equals 3, and ACherryIsA has no related enum member for this value...

Answer (score 1):

If the flags are mutually exclusive, you can get the names like this:

```
((ACherryIsA[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(ACherryIsA)))
.Where(e => twoOfThree.HasFlag(e))
```

Demo:

```
var twoOfThree = ACherryIsA.Fruit | ACherryIsA.Tree;
Console.WriteLine(
    "Name: " + String.Join(
        ",", 
        ((ACherryIsA[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(ACherryIsA)))
        .Where(e => twoOfThree.HasFlag(e))
    )
);   // => Name: Tree,Fruit
```

But this behaves weirdly if the flag has overlap:

```
[Flags]
public enum ACherryIsA
{
    Tree = 1,
    Fruit = 2,
    SorryWhatWasTheQuestionAgain = 4,
    FruitTree = Tree | Fruit,
}

public static void Main()
{
    var twoOfThree = ACherryIsA.Fruit | ACherryIsA.Tree;
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Name: " + String.Join(
            ",", 
            ((ACherryIsA[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(ACherryIsA)))
            .Where(e => twoOfThree.HasFlag(e))
        )
    );   // => Name: Tree,Fruit,FruitTree
}
```